# How do I merge tags or propose to merge tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I'm looking at various tags right now and I think that some tags, for instance "gene-expression" and "protein-expression", should be merged. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I made the protein-expression tag and I believe that I should retroactively switch it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tags are only on a handful of questions, just change the tags on those by hand. If it is on 10+ questions you can ask a moderator, we can merge tags without having to edit all the questions by hand.

In this case though [gene-expression](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gene-expression) and [protein-expression](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protein-expression) are not identical, they are used differently. They're not necessarily used clearly, but they shouldn't just be merged.

If we have some tags that are not used in a clear manner and you're unsure about how to proceed, you can always start a discussion about the tags here on meta or in chat.